# Changing Color When is Click jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to do something similar
I have this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#au').click(function(){
    $('#light1').css('background', 'yellow');
  });
  $('#cu').click(function(){
    $('#light2').css('background', 'yellow');
  });
});
```

Is working good but i want to remove the background of one of the div when i click on the other one. how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a `transparent` background to give the effect of a removed background, or you can set the background to `none`. In your case, it sounds like you'd want to go with the `background: none` option - see below.

**None:**

```
$('#cu').click(function(){
    $('#light2').css('background', 'none');
});
```

**Transparent:**

```
$('#cu').click(function(){
    $('#light2').css('background', 'transparent');
});
```

Comment: Thanks. It was adding another line with the previous background color for some reason i didn't thought about that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using IDs you should use classes:

```
$('.clickable').click(function(){
    $('.light').css('background', 'none');
    $('.light').eq($(this).data('light')).css('background', 'yellow');
});
```

This would work with HTML like:

```
<div class="light"></div>
<div class="light"></div>
<button id="au" class="clickable" data-light="0"/>
<button id="cu" class="clickable" data-light="1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#au').click(function(){
    $('#light1').toggleClass('yellow');
});
  $('#cu').click(function(){
    $('#light2').toggleClass('yellow');
  });
});
```